# OpenCV Canny after ConvexPoly not working

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform

I'm working on an lane detection algorithm with opencv in c++.
I did an Affine Transform to extract an triangular area to an mask.

After this step I want to perform the Canny edge detector. But it is not working. Is it due to the bit conversion? Or what is my Problem?

I outsourced the main part to the function warpTriangle. The porgram breaks in this function at the end.

Error Message:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((_dst.getObj() != _src.getObj() || _src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))) && "Inplace parameters are not supported") in Canny, file /tmp/opencv-20180113-80339-d8g5mw/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp, line 935
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-20180113-80339-d8g5mw/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:935: error: (-215) (_dst.getObj() != _src.getObj() || _src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))) && "Inplace parameters are not supported" in function Canny`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTNoS.jpg)

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// Warps and alpha blends triangular regions from img1 and img2 to img
void warpTriangle(Mat &img1, Mat &img2, vector<Point2f> tri)
{
    // Find bounding rectangle for each triangle
    Rect r1 = boundingRect(tri);
    Rect r2 = boundingRect(tri);

    // Offset points by left top corner of the respective rectangles
    vector<Point2f> tri1Cropped, tri2Cropped;
    vector<Point> tri2CroppedInt;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tri1Cropped.push_back( Point2f( tri[i].x - r1.x, tri[i].y -  r1.y) );
        tri2Cropped.push_back( Point2f( tri[i].x - r2.x, tri[i].y - r2.y) );

        // fillConvexPoly needs a vector of Point and not Point2f
        tri2CroppedInt.push_back( Point((int)(tri[i].x - r2.x), (int)(tri[i].y - r2.y)) );

    }

    // Apply warpImage to small rectangular patches
    Mat img1Cropped;
    img1(r1).copyTo(img1Cropped);

    // Given a pair of triangles, find the affine transform.
    Mat warpMat = getAffineTransform( tri1Cropped, tri2Cropped );

    // Apply the Affine Transform just found to the src image
    Mat img2Cropped = Mat::zeros(r2.height, r2.width, img1Cropped.type());
    warpAffine( img1Cropped, img2Cropped, warpMat, img2Cropped.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_REFLECT_101);

    // Get mask by filling triangle
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(r2.height, r2.width, CV_32FC3);
    fillConvexPoly(mask, tri2CroppedInt, Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 16, 0);
    imshow("mask", mask);
    // Copy triangular region of the rectangular patch to the output image

    multiply(img2Cropped,mask, img2Cropped);

    img2Cropped.convertTo(img2Cropped, CV_8U);
    imshow("img2Cropped",img2Cropped);
    Canny(img2Cropped, img2Cropped, 50, 150);   <--- Breaks here!

}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{

  //  VideoCapture cap(0);
    // Challenge video
    VideoCapture cap("/Users/markus/Desktop/challenge.mp4");
    Mat imgIn;
    while (true)
    {
        Mat start;

        Mat frame = Mat(320,480, CV_8U, 0.0);
        cap >> start;

        resize(start, frame, frame.size());

        cout << "h: " << frame.rows << " w: " << frame.cols << endl;

        Mat imgIn = frame;

        // Read input image and convert to float
        imgIn.convertTo(imgIn, CV_32FC3, 1/255.0);

        // Output image is set to white
        Mat imgOut = Mat::ones(imgIn.size(), imgIn.type());
        imgOut = Scalar(0.0,0.0,0.0);

        int height, width;
        height = frame.rows;
        width = frame.cols;
        // Input triangle
        vector <Point2f> triIn;
        triIn.push_back(Point2f(0,height-1));
        triIn.push_back(Point2f(width-1,height-1));
        triIn.push_back(Point2f(width/2-1,height/2-1));

        // Warp all pixels inside input triangle to output triangle
         warpTriangle(imgIn, imgOut, triIn);

        // Draw triangle on the input and output image.

        // Convert back to uint because OpenCV antialiasing
        // does not work on image of type CV_32FC3

        imgIn.convertTo(imgIn, CV_8UC3, 255.0);
        imgOut.convertTo(imgOut, CV_8UC3, 255.0);

        // Draw triangle using this color
        Scalar color = Scalar(255, 150, 0);

        // cv::polylines needs vector of type Point and not Point2f
        vector <Point> triInInt, triOutInt;
        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            triInInt.push_back(Point(triIn[i].x,triIn[i].y));
        }

        // Draw triangles in input and output images
        polylines(imgIn, triInInt, true, color, 2, 16);
        polylines(imgOut, triOutInt, true, color, 2, 16);

        imshow("frame", imgIn);


        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you already what is wrong

> _dst.getObj() != _src.getObj()

This means that the source and the destination object should not be the same...

In your code you have:

```
Canny(img2Cropped, img2Cropped, 50, 150);
```

As you can see, you have the same variable as source and destination (img2Cropped). To fix it change it to:

```
Mat resultCanny;
Canny(img2Cropped, resultCanny, 50, 150);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code, and the error disappeared!

BUT, the edges aren't displaying. I only see an black image.. Is it possible to change the color of the detected edges to white?

Comment: @Markus that should be another question :) But I can tell you that you should check ` multiply(img2Cropped,mask, img2Cropped);` and `img2Cropped.convertTo(img2Cropped, CV_8U);`. Mask has 3 channels and then you multiply it to what i guess a colored image (looking at your results) and then you just force a conversion to 1 channel... you should change to greyscale first or something like that... also the mask is float... is the image also float? is it really needed in float?

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out & and create an new question. No it is not really necessary to be an float.

Comment: Then you can use CV_8UC3 for it (still 1 and 0 for your code to work) and the use cvtcolor with the flag COLOR_BGR2GRAY and then it will be in CV_8U which is what you need for canny. BTW, if the question solved your problem, don't forget to accept it so that other people with similar problems know that it is a working solution :)

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! I will accept your solution :). (Another question: Do you know any good reference or book in english or german to learn opencv?)

Comment: I think the one I knew it is outdated :( it was "learning OpenCV"... I think it is better to find tutorials about it and read the documentation.